# Python number format muddle

Tags: python, formatting

Please put me out of my misery. The following example seems to be using `y` twice rather than `y` and then `m`.

```
>>> m=8
>>> y=11
>>> print '20{0:02d}{0:02d}01'.format(y, m)
20111101
```

I've been through as much of the documentation as I can but can't figure out what would have been relatively straightforward with the old procedure:

```
>>> print '20%02d%02d01' % ( y, m )
20110801
```

If someone could explain where I'm going wrong I'd be really grateful.

Comment: `'20{0:02d}{0:02d}01'` should be `'20{0:02d}{1:02d}01'`

Comment: Even simpler: `'20{:02d}{:02d}01'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
print '20{0:02d}{1:02d}01'.format(y, m)
```

You referred to the first argument twice.

Comment: Doh! Thanks. I read the Python docs over and over but still missed this.

Comment: You could leave out the 0 and 1 indexes (keep the colons though). You only need them if you want to reuse the args multiple times or if you want to reorder them.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> print '20{0:02d}{1:02d}01'.format(y, m)
```

you need to use the next arg in the arg list.